# Verify that W is a subspace of V. Assume that V has the standard operations

Tags: linear-algebra

> $W = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^4 ; x_1, x_2, x_3 \text{ are real numbers}\}$
>
> $V = \mathbb{R}^4$

Can anyone help me with this kind of problem and explain it why?  Or just answer it and i will be the one to understand the answer.

Comment: What makes a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: Yes the question is in the titke

Comment: I know, but I'm not just gonna give you the answer. What does $W$ have to satisfy in order to be a subspace of $V$?

Comment: I think you need a 0,0 vectors in a subset to be in a subspace

Comment: Yes, we need that the null vector of $V$ be in $W$. What else?

Comment: You need to prove the scalar multi properties?

Comment: Yes. Since it appears you have a bit of hard time doing it, I'll help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, the $0$ vector of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is in $W$. Just take $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = 0$. Now for any two vectors $u = (x_1, x_2, x_3, 0)$ and $v = (v_1, v_2, v_3, 0)$ in $W$, we have that their sum, $u + v$, is also in $W$, and that $\lambda u \in W$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ (can you see why?). That's it, we're done.

Comment: Thank youu btw can i ask what is the meaning of aew and ae real numbers what is the meaning of symbol and e?

Comment: I don't understand your question, what do you want to know the meaning of? By the way, if it has helped you and you see fit, you can accept my answer by clicking the check mark on the side of it.

Comment: The last part wherein the symbol u and e w for any symbol e r(real numbers)  can u explain that?

Comment: Oh, I see. $\lambda$ represents any real number. So, you see that the vector $u = (1, 2, 3, 0)$ is in your subspace, right? Well, the vector $2u = (2, 3, 6, 0)$ is also in your subspace. It turns out that no matter what $u$ I take, any multiple of it, that is, $\lambda u$, is also there! That's the meaning of what I wrote. Do you have more questions?

Comment: Bte what is the meaning of that dollar sign?  And 2u equals to (2,4,6,0)right?

Comment: I think your confusion comes from the fact that you're (probably) reading this on a mobile device (on a computer everything looks as it should). The dollar signs is just the proper way to format math here. And yes, $2u = (2, 4, 6, 0)$.

Comment: Yes im on mobile im sorrt :( and how can it be 3 not 4?

Comment: It's 4, you're correct. I typed it wrong, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying 

Comment: Can i ask how do you solve the u + v which is the x1, x2, x3, 0 and v1, v2, v3, 9

Comment: Just sum coordinate to coordinate like you're used to.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: (X1+v1+x2+v2+x3+v3+0+0) is this right? =(xv(1,2,3),0+0)

Comment: Sure, I can give an example. $(1,2,3,0) +(4,5,6,0)=(5,7,9,0)$.

Comment: How can you add the real numbers?

Comment: Well, the same way everyone learns, there's nothing new, just like in my example.

Comment: But how you cant add the different letters right which is the x and v so how can i add it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: How can i prove the summation of u and v based on your solution

Comment: You just need to show that the last coordinate is $0$. To do that, you do the sum $0+0$.

Comment: Thank you :) my conclusion is therefore w is a subspace of r4